# Run executable in a silent mode

Tags: c#, exe

I am executing .exe file in C# using the code below.
If I want to run executable in a silent mode I usually uncomment UseShellExecute and RedirectStandardOutput properties, but this gives me an error:

> Unhandled Exception: System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception: The system cannot find the file specified

If I keep a code like this it runs, but the additional command line screen is popping up and closing.
I am running Poisson Surface Reconstruction .exe and wondering if the silent mode is possible or not? Or it must be implemented by author who did this executable?

```
var proc = new System.Diagnostics.Process {
        StartInfo = new System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo {
            FileName = "PoissonRecon",
            Arguments = "--in " + fileNameIn + " --out " + fileName + " --depth "+depth.ToString()+" --pointWeight 0 --colors",
            //UseShellExecute = false,
            //RedirectStandardOutput = true,
            CreateNoWindow = true,
            WorkingDirectory = filePath
        }
    };

    proc.Start();
    proc.WaitForExit();
```

Comment: Does the command work normally? without setting those options, given that possonrecon would need to be in the current directory or path..

Comment: The code runs it produces the result, just not in a silent mode.

Comment: it probably needs to be done in tandom with the original app owner

Answer (score 0):

Try adding to arguments line this:
"--mode unattended"
if I'm not mistaken it should make installation silent

Comment: The OP didn't say it was an installation they were running